# How to standardise a column of mixed date formats in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

Got a table in SQL Server which contains a `varchar` column with date data. Unfortunately the dates are in a whole slew of different formats.

```
2012-05-01
27/05/2012 
07MAY2014
19/07/13
```

There may be others, but that's all I've encountered so far.

I need to squeeze these into a `datetime` column into another table, so I've been trying to select them as standard date-time values. At first, I thought that'd be easy:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myDateColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME, myDateColumn, 103)
WHERE ISDATE(myDateColumn) = 0
```

But the trouble is that SQL Server treats `dd/mm/yy` and `dd/mm/yyyy` as separate formats. The former is code 3, and the latter is code 103. So whichever way I run that update, it chokes on the opposite format.

Is there any way I can select/update based on the date format, and get all these dates converted to a single valid `DateTime` format?

Comment: Date conversion is a weakness for SQL Server (and others).  If you can use CLR then you can write .NET code to parse your date times and this is probably the best method available.  Failing that you are going to have to do some donkey work to try and determine which format the date is in before parsing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you just have to try to differentiate between the different classes and handle each case in the appropriate way. Something like this:

```
declare @tab table (d varchar(20))
insert @tab values ('2012-05-01'),('27/05/2012'),('07MAY2014'),('19/07/13')

select 
    case 
        when isnumeric(left(d,4)) = 1 then cast(d as date) 
        when len(d) = 10 then convert(date, d, 103) 
        when len(d) = 8 then convert(date, d, 3) 
        when charindex('/',d) = 0 and isnumeric(d) = 0 then convert(date, d, 106) 
    end as [date]
from @tab
```

Output:

```
date
----------
2012-05-01
2012-05-27
2014-05-07
2013-07-19
```

It might not be that efficient, but I presume this is a one-off operation. I didn't write it as an update statement, but the query should be easy to adapt, and you should consider adding the converted date as a new proper datetime column if possible in my opinion.

Edit: here's the corresponding update statement:

```
update @tab
set d = 
    case 
        when isnumeric(left(d,4)) = 1 then cast(d as date) 
        when len(d) = 10 then convert(date, d, 103) 
        when len(d) = 8 then convert(date, d, 3) 
        when charindex('/',d) = 0 and isnumeric(d) = 0 then convert(date, d, 106) 
    end 
from @tab
```

Comment: Thanks - I assumed it'd be something like this, but I couldn't see a way to use the string handling functions to differentiate the data. FYI this is imported data so it's safe to overwrite directly rather than add a column.

Comment: I guess the last `when` used to handle the case `07MAY2014` but in fact that case can be converted using the default expression: `convert(date, '07MAY2014')` (so no specific style needed).

Comment: @KingKing I believe it's locale dependent and the default did not work in my non-"us-english" installation, but I guess you're correct in this case, good to know anyway.

Comment: it's just the problem of the current language setting, it should be English, such as if it's `Deutsch`, the date should be `07MAI2014` (`MAI` is short month of `MAY` in Deutsch). Also I read about the style of `106` in SQL Server 2000 reference, it says the format is `dd mon yy`, not sure why you use it (any reference?). When I try setting language to a non-English one (using syntax `set language {language}`), using `convert(date, '07MAY2014', 106)` won't work.

Comment: @KingKing I picked 106 as I felt that it was the closest match, and it did work for me, and apparently for the OP too I guess. I'm not sure which style would have been better. `dd mon yy` also includes `dd mon yyyy` if I read the docs (for 2008) right.

Comment: not sure what is happening on your side, but on my side `106` does nothing. You can try executing `set language 'English'` before running your query and you'll see `convert(date, '07MAY2014')` works like a charm. Also I would like to know what language name is in your current setting, (try `select @@language` in case you might not know about it). BTW, although I read SQL Server 2000 reference but I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @KingKing I were wrong, my test database indeed uses English, and `convert(date, '07MAY2014')` works fine, don't know why it didn't work before, maybe I did something different.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012, you could use `try_convert()`.  Otherwise, you could multiple updates:

```
UPDATE myTable 
    SET myDateColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME, myDateColumn, 103)
    WHERE ISDATE(myDateColumn) = 0 AND MyDateColumn like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';

UPDATE myTable 
    SET myDateColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME, myDateColumn, 3)
    WHERE ISDATE(myDateColumn) = 0 AND MyDateColumn like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]';
```

Note:  the `where` clause will probably work here for the `update`.  It does not work for a `select`.  You may need to use a `case` as well:

```
UPDATE myTable 
    SET myDateColumn = (CASE WHEN ISDATE(myDateColumn) = 0 AND MyDateColumn like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

                             THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, myDateColumn, 103)
                             ELSE myDateColumn
                        END)
    WHERE ISDATE(myDateColumn) = 0 AND MyDateColumn like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-0]'
```

Also, you are putting the values back in the same column so you are overwriting the original data -- and you have another implicit conversion back to a string  I would strongly recommend that you add another column to the table with a `datetime` data type and put the correctly-typed value there.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally horrid, but it works with your example:

```
DECLARE @DodgyDates TABLE (
    DateString VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @DodgyDates VALUES ('2012-05-01');
INSERT INTO @DodgyDates VALUES ('27/05/2012'); 
INSERT INTO @DodgyDates VALUES ('07MAY2014');
INSERT INTO @DodgyDates VALUES ('19/07/13');
SELECT * FROM @DodgyDates;
--SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DateString) FROM @DodgyDates;--Fails
WITH DateDeconstruct AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE
            WHEN DateString LIKE '____-__-__' THEN DateString
            WHEN DateString LIKE '__/__/____' THEN RIGHT(DateString, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(DateString, 4, 2) + '-' + LEFT(DateString, 2)
            WHEN DateString LIKE '__/__/__' THEN '20' + RIGHT(DateString, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(DateString, 4, 2) + '-' + LEFT(DateString, 2)
            WHEN DateString LIKE '_________' THEN RIGHT(DateString, 4) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MM, DateString)) + '-' + LEFT(DateString, 2)
        END AS FixedString
    FROM
        @DodgyDates)
SELECT
    DateString AS OriginalDate,
    FixedString AS FixedDate,
    CONVERT(DATE, FixedString) AS ConvertedDate
FROM
    DateDeconstruct;
```

Results are:

```
OriginalDate    FixedDate   ConvertedDate
2012-05-01  2012-05-01  2012-05-01
27/05/2012  2012-05-27  2012-05-27
07MAY2014   2014-5-07   2014-05-07
19/07/13    2013-07-19  2013-07-19
```

Answer (score 0):

For this first you can convert all the data into another format such as `110` the `USA date fromat`, and then further again update the whole table with the desired format.

Comment: What? This just results in a failure to convert to the USA date format first.

Comment: Well this ws just a suggestion. Sorry for not working.